# Edge Selection - Selection highlights vertices only?

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

The first picture is showing how the edge selection should look. The second picture is mine, it is showing how my selection looks.

I'm trying to join the bridge of the nose and my selection looks different on
screen, only the vertices seems to be selected but the edges are not.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Select all vertices (A) then remove doubles (W > Remove Doubles). When you select two verts and the edge between them isn't highlighted, it often means one of the verts you selected is duplicate and not part of that common edge.

Comment: @ TLousky you might want to create a proper answer with clear steps below for future question seekers with this comment issue when they first start learning blender.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your image, you are in vertex selection mode, that doesn't explain why the edge in between the two selected vertices isn't highlighted, so most probably you have doubles. Select all by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice, then  <kbd>W</kbd>  and choose remove doubles, watch the status bar at the header of Blender to see how many vertices are removed, this should work normally, you can set selection by edges instead of vertices by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Tab</kbd>  then choose Edge.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd> on an Edge will select **Edge Loop**.

You can find more information about selecting Edges in the [Blender Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/edges.html)

Comment: Oh my god. It selects the whole edge of the eye. I meant, I want to select the bridge of the nose only and connect it to the other side.

Answer (score 0):

To select multiple edges, faces, verts (dependent on being in edge, face, or vertices select mode), you can use  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +   <kbd>RMB</kbd>

Comment: Doing that it selects the dots (vertices?)